# Mathematical Analysis: Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is a question from my Mid-term test which was held last week:

Define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x,$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x) =0$, otherwise

Is $f \in R[0,1]?$

My Proof:
Consider any Partition $P = \{\ x_{0} = 0, ..., x_{n} =1\}$ of $[0,1]$. Then, $L(f,P)=0$ but $U(f,P)$ $= \sum^{n}_{i=1} sup \{\ f(x): x\in [x_{i-1},x_i] \} (x_i -x_{i-1}) $ $ =\sum^{n}_{i=1} x_i(x_i -x_{i-1}) \geq \sum^{n}_{i=1} x_1(x_i -x_{i-1}) = x_{1} >0$

But the hint in the question requires one to show that $U(f,P) > \frac{1}{2}$ . Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use AM-GM to prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_{i-1} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac12(x_1^2+x_n^2)-\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} x_i^2 >\frac12.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
$$x_i\gt \frac{x_i+x_{i-1}}{2}.$$
 Then use **telescoping.**